# Is there is a way to do JQL search t9 identify the users who are using past due epic link to their story?

Tags: jql, jira-agile

i am trying to create a JQL query to identify all the users who are using the past due Epic in their story which are not in Done, Cancelled status. Can someone please help?

So far my query looks like this but it is not showing the result

Project=abcd and assignee not in (inactiveUser()) and status not in (done,cancelled) and issuetype =Epic and due>=now()